# When parent is position relative child elements not clickable

Tags: css

I have a div with position relative because another child element is position absolute. However, I also have a button that becomes unclickable. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot help you without your example code. We are not clairvoyants.

Comment: Can you share some code or example please ? So we can help you :)

Comment: Maybe you need to set the child to {z-index: 1} to get it to be at the top layer?